# MySQL: how can i convert a string '1,2,3,4' to a (1,2,3,4) so i'll be able to use it in a 'where X in ()' statement

Tags: mysql

I ran a query that resulted in the string `'1,2,3,4'`.

How can I run a second query that treats that string as a list of numbers. So I'll be able to do:

```
select * from tbl where name not in (1,2,3,4)
```

I would like an answer in pure MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well first of all, this usually means that your database structure is not good; you should [normalize](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) your database.

However, you can do what you want, with the `FIND_IN_SET` function:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(name, '1,2,3,4')
```

Comment: +1 On the normalization. Sounds like the OP really should be able to say SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name NOT IN (subquery).

Comment: Might i could give you +100, You can't even imagine what that answers

Answer (score 2):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select * from tbl where FIND_IN_SET(name, '1,2,3,4') = 0
```

Like the other answer, I would also recommend normalizing your database if at all possible. This query could be slow as it will require a scan of the table. Even if there is an index on name this query won't be able to use it efficiently.